# Php division with no decimal separate result

Tags: php

The thing i want to do is :

```
   $numbertodivise = 500;

   500 / 3 = 166,66
```

I want to divise the number in the most equitable part and the last part to add the difference , exemple :

```
  500 / 3 will give me :
  $result1 = 166
  $result2 = 166
  $result3 = 168
```

i want the code for every division how is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Say what? Can you explain in a different way?

Comment: Have a look at [`intdiv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php). For the last part you can add the modulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have extracted the remainder of the `numbertodivise` e.g. 2 if modulus with 3, and later I divided and extracted the integer part of the division so that I can add the remainder into last divided number i.e. 166 in this case.

```
<?php
$numbertodivise = 500;
$no = 3;

$intnumber = intval($numbertodivise / $no);
$rem = $numbertodivise % $no;
$array = [];

for($i=1;$i<=$no;$i++) {
    if($i==$no) {
        $array[] = $intnumber + $rem;
    } else {
        $array[] = $intnumber;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
?>
```

Output will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 166
    [1] => 166
    [2] => 168
)
```

For making variables as you mentioned use:

```
<?php list($result1, $result2, $result3) = $array; ?>
```

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard explanation added

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7, you can use this function (check comment for <7):

```
function get_results($val, $qt){
    $division = intdiv($val, $qt); // PHP <7: $division = ($val - ($val % $qt)) / $qt;
    $ret = array_fill(0, $qt, $division); // fill array with $qt equal values
    if($division != $val / $qt){ // if not whole division, add remaning to lsat element
        $ret[count($ret)-1] = $ret[0] + ($val % $qt);
    }return $ret;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
print_r(get_results(500, 3));
```

And the output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 166
    [1] => 166
    [2] => 168
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it using `intval()` and the modulo operator `%`:

```
<?php
    $divide = 500;
    $divideWith = 3;

    for($i=0; $i < $divideWith; $i++)
    {
        echo "This is result".($i+1).": ";

        // If $i is not on the last iteration
        if($i != $divideWith-1)
            // intval() returns integer part without rounding. It
            // floors the value inside the parenthesese.
            echo intval($divide/$divideWith).'<br/>';
        else
            // ($divide % $divideWidth) will return the remainder of
            // division between $divide and $divideWidth. 
            // The remainder is always an int value.
            echo (int($divide/$divideWith) + ($divide % $divideWith)).'<br/>';
    }
?>
```

The result of which will be:

```
This is result1: 166
This is result2: 166
This is result3: 168
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips, I was thinking of _try_ if you like it, not _try_ as if I don't know what I'm doing. I edited my answer to be more readable. Thanks.

Comment: "This works" still doesn't explain your methodology or what you changed.

Comment: OK. Hopefully your down-voter will come back and remove their vote.

Comment: It would be nice, but not necessary. Hopefully :) Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

A method that does not loop and uses basic PHP functions.

I use array_fill to fill the array with the floor of the calculation.
Then I add the remainder to the last item in the array.

```
$number = 500;
$divise =3;

$arr = array_fill(0, $divise, floor($number/$divise));
$arr[count($arr)-1] += $number-(floor($number/$divise)*$divise);
// Above line can also be . $arr[count($arr)-1] += $number-$arr[0]*$divise;
Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/hFrDc